# Implementing Web API Identity

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I am trying to find an up to date, clear and simple explanation of an implementation of ASP.NET Identity. The problem is that most tutorials get bogged down with Entity Framework discussions or branching off into territory which, while useful, is best for those who probably know "Identity" already.

TL:DR; I would like a link to a good description of how to implement ASP.NET Identity.

Comment: I don't know if you found John Atten blog [First Part](http://johnatten.com/2014/09/21/asp-net-identity-2-0-introduction-to-working-with-identity-2-0-and-web-api-2-2/), [2dn Part](http://johnatten.com/2014/10/26/asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2-0-customizing-identity-models-and-implementing-role-based-authorization/) but he have pretty nice stuff, maybe it can help you.

Comment: Thank you, that's great to have - hadn't seen it yet.